# Changing the fill of an SVG image in P5.js

Tags: svg, p5.js

I have a basic program that essentially just displays an imported svg. Is there any way I can change the fill of the svg?

```
var img;

function preload() {
  img = loadImage("assets/svgImage.svg")
}

function setup() {

  createCanvas(720, 400);
  background(200);
  fill(204, 101, 192, 127);
  stroke(127, 63, 120);

  image(img, 50, 50, 50, 50)

}
```

I tried something along the lines of:

```
function setup() {

  img.drawingContext.fillStyle = '#475731'
  image(img, 50, 50, 50, 50)

}
```

But that doesn't seem to do anything for me.

Answer (score 1):

http://zenozeng.github.io/p5.js-svg/examples/#manipulating

The example on the "Manipulating existing SVG" page says you need to use the `querySVG` function to obtain the path/shape components, then you can modify their `fill` attribute.

This is the example given:

```
var svg, path;
function preload() {
    svg = loadSVG('test.svg');
    frameRate(20);
}

function setup() {
    createCanvas(600, 200, SVG);
    image(svg, 0, 0, 200, 200);
    path = querySVG('path')[1];
}

function draw() {
    // update line width of 2nd line
    path.attribute('stroke-width', frameCount % 20);
    if (frameCount === 18) {
        noLoop();
        save(); // save current SVG graphics
    }
}
```

I imagine in your case it would be:

```
path.attribute('fill', '#475731');
```

Comment: Ok, so nothing native in p5? It's fine, I just thought I'd check before adding a plugin.

Comment: So I've played around with this plugin and I don't think it works for me. I have an enormous numbers of shapes that get rendered really nicely (and fast) in canvas, but screeches to a halt when the plugin translates all shapes to an SVG. Ideally, I'd like to be able to just draw an SVG (with my amended color) and then paint it onto the canvas. It seems like this plugin forces me to render the entire canvas as an SVG and I'm not sure that works for my use case.